# Insert new record and Update MySQL table records .- PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a MySQL table.

```
|id|page  |page_number
|1 |name1 |3
|2 |name2 |2
|3 |name3 |1
|4 |name2 |4
```

The user can add new page, but after current page. For the example current page is 1(page number), then new page (page number) must be 2, then all other pages after 1 must be updated page number+1 and insert new page with page number=2. Or may be first I must insert new page and then update all page numbers ?

What is the standart solution here, is there standart solution ?

I tried with foreach like that:

```
$count = 1;
// loop over all pages 
foreach($pages->fetchAll() as $page){
    // if count is less than new-page order then continue add 1 to       
    // counter
    if($new_page_order > $count){
       $count++;
       continue;
    }

    // get unique id for current page
    $current_id = $page['id'];
    $new_order= $count+1;

    // update current page with page_order+1
    $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE pages SET    
             page_order='".$new_order."' WHERE id=".$current_id);
    $query->execute();
    //add +1 to count, because it is used for page_order value
    $count++;
}
// add new page
$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO pages (columns... page_order)     
VALUES( values , ..., $new_page_order)");
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: It appears you are asking how to keep the pages synchronized. Wouldn't it best to use the id field as the page number instead since it already exists?

Comment: But id is unique. For the example (same situation), how can I increment +1 each row if next row has same value : `code` UPDATE pages SET id=id+1 WHERE ... `code` . I mean next id has same value that previous id must have or 1,2,3,4 must be 2,3,4,5 .

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to update only page numbers which are after the inserted one, you can run query like:

```
"UPDATE pages SET page_number = page_number + 1 WHERE page_number >= ".$current_id
```

before insertion is done